# Angular 5 form validations using Validators import

Tags: forms, validation, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm completely new in angular 5 and I'm trying to create a form with validations using Validators import from '@angular/forms'. Also I'm using bootstrap 4 to show some colors and texts regarding to valid or invalid form. The issue with that is when I want to show a red border color in an input, it appears green because is not getting for the condition from "Validator.required", but this is a bit weird because it's showing text that is required to fill this field. Trying different ways I used a "required" condition directly in input and "was-validated" (bootstrap class) showed the red color in the input, but I think that this is not the correct way to do that because I'm using the "Validators.required" in my typeScript file.

**data.component.html (with required)**

```
<h4>Formularios <small>data</small></h4>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarCambios()" novalidate>

  <div>

    <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'was-validated': (forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.required || forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength) && forma.controls['nombre'].touched}">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
      <div class="col-8">

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="nombre" required>

        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.required">
          El nombre es necesario.
        </div>

        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength">
          Por lo menos 3 caracteres.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Apellido</label>
      <div class="col-8">

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" formControlName="apellido">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Correo</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" formControlName="correo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        Guardar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**data.component.html (without required)**

```
<h4>Formularios <small>data</small></h4>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarCambios()" novalidate>

  <div>

    <div class="form-group row" 
         [ngClass]="{'was-validated': (forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.required || 
                    forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength) && 
                    forma.controls['nombre'].touched}">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
      <div class="col-8">

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="nombre">

        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.required">
          El nombre es necesario.
        </div>

        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength">
          Por lo menos 3 caracteres.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Apellido</label>
      <div class="col-8">

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" formControlName="apellido">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Correo</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" formControlName="correo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            Guardar
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**data.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validator, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-data",
  templateUrl: "./data.component.html",
  styles: []
})
export class DataComponent {
  forma: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.forma = new FormGroup({
      nombre: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      apellido: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      correo: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$")
      ])
    });
  }

  guardarCambios() {
    console.log(this.forma.value);
    console.log(this.forma);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please reduce the code here to a minimum verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)